# LetsEncrypt - setting up on existing domain, that doesn't currently point to the server

Tags: lets-encrypt

I'm currently setting up a new Linode server for my domain, and as part of that I'm installing LetsEncrypt. I've got it all installed, and I'm in the process of trying to verify the domain:

```
certbot certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/srv/www/foo.pro/www -d foo.pro -d www.foo.pro
```

I have added `/srv/www/foo.pro/www/.well-known` as a directory, and putting a test file in there I can then access it from the web.

I believe the issue is that I'm using my local host file (on my PC) to point to the new server (to overwrite the public DNS records), so:

```
45.79.1.236 foo.pro www.foo.pro
```

This works perfectly from my browser, but I can't figure out how to make LetsEncrypt also use this. My /etc/hosts file seems ok as far as I can tell:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       debian
45.79.1.236     foo foo.pro

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

...but I have a feeling its not relying on that, but the public DNS instead?

There must be a way around this - as I'm sure lots of people need to setup the SSL certificates *before* making a site live =)

Thanks!

Comment: Just turn off your nginx/apache server - add the A record and alias for @ and www to the server IP. Run the LetsEncrypt script. As soon as it's registered, remove the DNS records and you're done.

Comment: If the site is already running, you'll need some downtime to support this. I tried for quite some time trying to fool it - but it's a no go. It actually registers your certificate with LetsEncrypt, and the processing is done on their end, not yours - that's why hosts files make no difference

Comment: @Trent - ah balls, that sucks! Thanks for the tip though - at least I won't spend hours trying to get it working :)